# How do I disable the middle click in Loki?

Tags: release-loki, touchpad, click

Im am using Elementary OS on a laptop and clicking in the middle of the trackpad's buttons would trigger a middle click. I would like to disable that.

Comment: This [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/620964/disable-middle-click-emulation) on askubuntu worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Running the following command in the terminal could solve this:

```
xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 25 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
```

To make this persistent, edit your ~/.Xmodmap with a text editor either from the terminal:

```
nano ~/.Xmodmap
```

or with a graphical text editor:

> open files --> go to your home directory --> open .Xmodmap (a hidden
>   file) with a right click in "Scratch" or another text editor. If the
>   file doesn't exist, create a new file with the name .Xmodmap

and add this line

```
pointer = 1 25 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Be great if I could remap middle click to left click instead of disabling it.