# How do I turn middle click into left click?

Tags: touchpad, click

I can't have middle click closing apps when I accidentally tap it.  Best solution I've found is to [disable](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7851/how-do-i-disable-the-middle-click-in-loki) middle click entirely.  I'd rather not have a big deadspot in the middle of trackpad.

I'd rather expand my trackpad so that middle click is treated as a left click.  I also want left click to continue to be a left click.  How can I do this?

I tried:

`me@pc:~/grive$ xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 1 3"
Warning: Only changing the first 3 of 10 buttons.
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  116 (X_SetPointerMapping)
  Value in failed request:  0x1
  Serial number of failed request:  9
  Current serial number in output stream:  9`

P.S. (I don't know if Im on Loki or how to tell.  I just downloaded elementary OS and installed it the weekend of 5/12/2017)

Comment: This is one of the major pain points I have so far. Hopefully somebody will have an answer.